# Example of injective tensorproduct that does not respect quotient operator (Ex.3.4. Ryan)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

I'm stucking on this for a while and really hope to get some help:

Let $Q: l_1 \rightarrow c_0$ a quotient operator (linear and bounded), that means Q is surjective, ||Q|| = 1 and maps the open unit ball of $l_1$ onto the open unit ball of $c_0$. Let I be the identity operator on $l_1$. I have to show that $I \otimes_\varepsilon Q: l_1 \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon l_1 \rightarrow c_0 \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon l_1$ is NOT a quotient operator.

The Operatornorm of $I \otimes_\varepsilon Q$ is 1, according to Prop.3.2 (Ryan's Book) and I've figured out  that the operator need not to be surjective, but how to show that? Every ideas are appreciated !

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/